# navigate flutter apps with dynamic parameters

Tags: flutter, webview, navigation-drawer

I am trying to route from my homepage to webview page. it works fine if i click on any button press. but if i click the drawer menu item it just shows me error instead of show that page. the error:

```
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
This Overlay widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets.
```

my webview call from drawer menu click:

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/details',
        arguments: ScreenArguments(
          'Pay Now',
          "https://www.test.com/"+_customerID,
        ));
```

can you please suggest me where is the main issue here and how to solve it. thanks in advance

Comment: no...  I am using "onPressed" event

Comment: Add the code for onPressed property

Comment: sorry... i am using onTap event  `new ListTile(
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left:50.0),
                leading: new Icon(Icons.web),
                title: new Text("Pay Now"),
                selected: 3 == _selectedDrawerIndex,
                onTap: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/details',
        arguments: ScreenArguments(
          'Pay Now',
          "https://www.test.com/"+_customerID,
        ));
              ),`

Comment: are u using setState in your code?

Comment: yes.. I am using setState() in my Homepage where my drawer menu is located